# How to generate random even numbers between a given interval?

Tags: c++

I want to get a set of random even numbers between 50 and 100, and this is what I wrote:

```
    int x;
    x=(2*(50+rand()%(100-50+1)));
```

when I output this, I get 
186
166
112
190
150
160
146
104
194
168
194
178
102
200
192
130
168
134
146
184
136

which are not in between 50 and 100...why?

thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation is wrong, you ask for 2 times a number between 50 and 100.

Go with

```
x = 2 * ( rand() % 25 ) + 50
```

Comment: This will never yield 100

Comment: @Vince: "Between 50 and 100" often doesn't mean including 100 (_all_ iterator ranges in C++ being an obvious example). The OP needs to specify before we can pass judgement.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x;
x=50+(2*(rand()%(26)));
```

Comment: The only one that seems to have paid attention to the *even* requirement

Answer (score -1):

X = rand()%(upper-lower+1) + lower

In your case : x = rand()%51 + 50